# Going Live with paypal MECL library for ios app?Getting live App id and paypal device id?

Tags: paypal

I'm using paypal MECL for my app.I'm going to live with my app soon.For that I need live app id.So I went to x.com to submit my app.Where MECL is listed as deprecated.Though I can select that option.
My Question:

1.Is it ok to use MECL still now?
2.For submitting app there is option to submit ad-hoc build.Where do I get the paypal device id to add my build?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a APP, you will need to

- login to developer.paypal.com(with your live paypal account credentials)
- Dashboard->Application->[My APPS](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps)->Create App

Once created, you will get `Client ID` and `Secret` which you can use in your integration.

Comment: I'm not using adaptive payment, i'm just using mobile express checkout.If it is only MECL don't we need to submit app to paypal?
Then how do i get live app id ?Thanks